# Finding the combinations of variables to maximize( or minimize) a function

Tags: python

I have a 2D list. Consider it to be possibleVals. Each sub list within this 2D list contains possible values for a given variable.

*i.e If the 2D list contains m 1D lists it implies that there are m variables. with the i th variable will having possible values contained within possibleVals[i].*

**I want to find the optimal combination for all the m variables. to maximize a certain function based of the inputs**. I understand we could derive all the combinations and find the value one by one but that is very time consuming especially as m grows. I was wondering whether there is a solution for this using machine learning (Neural nets) as it has a similar behaviour (of course involving reducing a certain value

Comment: this sounds like a instance of a combinatorial optimisation problem. maybe start your search here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization. numpy's optimisation package might also be of interest https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html . Certain classes of these problems are easy, others are hard, but without knowing more about your particular problem, its impossible to tell.